# How to make a input field expand vertically and not horizontally when you type?

Tags: javascript, html, css

## The problem

I made an input. Now when I type, the input will adjust it's size so it fits the amount of text inside it. Now the problem is that I tried to look for some answers on the internet, but all of then expand horizontally, but I want it that when it reaches a certain point, then it will expand vertically instead of horizontally. I also **DO NOT** want to make a span or div with contenteditable. How can I do this?

### Some code

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into `<textarea />` element?

Comment: Um yes, but the goal is to make it an input tag, and not anything else.

Comment: @DrakeKrewson why does it have to be an input tag?

Comment: `<input type="text"` only allows 1 line. You need to use a textarea as mentioned by @MK

Comment: ok I will try to hook it up using a textarea tag. If that doesn't work I will notify you.

Comment: nvm I don't want it to be expandable.

Answer (score 2):

Inputs are only for single line inputs. It's not even possible to add new lines in an input.

What you're looking for is a textarea that fits the height of the content. This is possible with JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener("input", function(){
  this.style.height = '0px';
  this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: um I don't want it to be expandable.

Comment: @Drake *"I want it that when it reaches a certain point, then it will expand vertically"*

Comment: I think @DrakeKrewson means that he doesn't want the user to resize it

Comment: Adding `textarea { resize: vertical; }` or `textarea { resize: none; }` in CSS should fix it

Comment: ok I got it. I will try.

Comment: um that made the css go haywire. didn't work

Comment: @DrakeKrewson could you provide your full HTML and CSS?

Comment: um where? My html is huge so I can't post it here.